# Jquery filter results grey out unused letters A-Z

Tags: jquery, filter

If I get a recordset from a mySQL database of 10 names, I can use jquery to filter those by first letter. However, if I had a link on a page for every letter of the alphabet, and wanted to grey out the ones that did not have any "results", how would I do this?

Here is how I am currently filtering the results:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function filterResults(letter){
        $('p').hide();
        $('p').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() === letter;
        }).show();
    };
    filterResults('A');
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var letter = $(this).html();            
        filterResults(letter);        
    });
});
```

Fiddle of the example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/livinzlife/8UE6m/

What I would like is for all letters unaccounted for to be grey. I have no idea how to select those that are unaccounted for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $p = $('p');
$('a').addClass(function(){
    var a = this.textContent;
    return $p.filter(function(){
       return this.textContent.charAt(0) === a
    }).length ? 'green' : 'grey';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLxKU/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a method like this

```
function showSupported(){
    // get the first letter of each p element in an array
    var supported = $('p').hide().map(function() {
        return $(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }).get(); 

    // make array unique;
    supported = $.grep(supported, function(v, k) {
        return $.inArray(v, supported) === k;
    });

    // find all a elements whose letter is not in the supported array
    $('a').filter(function(){
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), supported) === -1;
    }).addClass('grey'); // adding a class that makes them grey or whatever..
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8UE6m/1/

(*it doesn't handle the `0-9` numeric scenario, but you should be able to work on it*)

Answer (score 0):

A quick (not most efficient) way, would be something like...

```
var letters = "";
//Change the selector below to be more specific
//Go through <p>'s and get first letter
$('p').each(function() { 
var aText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
  //Guard against empty
  letters += aText ? aText.substring(0,1) : '';
});
//Loop through the A's
$('a').each(function() {
  if(letters.indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) < 1) {
     //One way is to replace the anchor tag with a span, which can't be clicked
     $(this).replaceWith('<span style="color:grey;">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
  }
});
```

Not sure if there are any errors in the snippet there, since I just banged it out. Hopefully you get the idea. Grab the first letter of each paragraph tag and put into a string.
Loop through each anchor tag, get the text, and see if it occurs in the string we created.
If not, replace it with a span, so the user can't click on it and color it grey.
If you really want just the anchor tag to be grey, change the above and apply a class to it or something (ie: `$('a').addClass(...)`).

Perhaps worth noting there are JavaScript/LINQ scripts out there (ie to do 'not contains' or 'where' clauses), but using them is likely to incur a performance penalty.